# Does data returned api method of Facebook safe?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, security, facebook-php-sdk

I use the [facebook-php-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-php-sdk) to perform user login. In some cases, I use the user's email on the Facebook as a key to login. The user data I get from:

```
$facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

Do this data safe? In other word, could some one able to change data sent by it?

To describe more suppose the following:

> There is an administrator user on my website whom his email on my
>   website is: admin@mywebsite.com. There is a hacker has a Facebook
>   account  with email: hacker@hk.hk.  Could this hacker able to inject
>   his email returned from the api method before it received from my
>   website to admin@mywebsite.com, so he will logged in as admin?

Comment: Instead of email, can you map your scenario to Facebook Id?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena It is very good suggestion. However, does any hacker able to modify the data sent by the Facebook, becuse even the Facebook Id is used, it may be changed too, if my fears are true of course!

Comment: User can change his email Id, and after authenticating the id by accessing the message sent by Facebook to the new Email Id. But user can't change his/her Facebook Id. It remains the same.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena Changing email in the Facebook account requires confirmation through a message sent to that email. In other word, the second email user should be regarded as the owner.

Comment: Well, both of the things, Facebook and Email can be hacked. Its just that I feel email are far more susceptible than Facebook account. And as Email can be hacked, so the Email Id of the Hacker can be changed to something you take for admin. Although getting the information as to what admin id is itself most of the work already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that the Facebook end points are using **HTTPS** I think there wouldn't be any altering in the data that you retrieved from these Facebook's end point.
The only way these can be altered is when someone gets access to SDK you are using and changes these end points to something else.

Comment: Could you, please, tell me where are those end points in the SDK? Or do you mean that only may happen on the Facebook side? In other word, the hacking action will occur on the Facebook itself!

Comment: These are defined in the [tag:facebook-php-sdk] using [`$DOMAIN_MAP`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L153) in `base_facebook.php` . And as they are outside from the Facebook's domain they might be altered by hacker for spurious activities.